# Azure Media Services - creating a small video player

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

If I was to use Azure Media Services to consume encoding of small video files and then playing back on a web app and mobile app, do i need to turn on the 'Streaming Endpoint' option? I am getting charged ~$65 a month just to have streaming endpoint, not sure if i need it.

The pricing doesn't quite make sense because I can get the same basic features from Vimeo for $7 a month.

Am I consuming this correctly?

Comment: How are you "playing back on a web app and mobile app"? After the video has been ingested (upload/encode) and published, the streaming endpoint+url parameters are what's fed into a media(video) player.

Answer (score 0):

> If I was to use Azure Media Services to consume encoding of small video files and then playing back on a web app and mobile app, do i need to turn on the 'Streaming Endpoint' option?

Yes, the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-streaming-endpoints-overview) explains that a streaming endpoint is the service that delivers content directly to the client application for live-streaming, video on demand, or progressive download.

So this means that you would need at least one streaming endpoint to be able to serve your videos to a client. A Media Services account already includes a default standard streaming endpoint. According to the documentation, this default streaming endpoint would be enough for the vast majority of workloads.

Take a look at the pricing page for more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/

According to the pricing page, the default streaming endpoint does cost ~$65/mo.

In regards to your comparison with Vimeo, the service that you end up using really depends on your particular case. While I understand pricing is a big factor when building an application, you should still consider the security of your videos at rest and in transit, scalability, availability of services, support, etc.